# to highlight text in textarea in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to highlight specific words in string in textarea using codeigniter. My input is `$string=array();` `$highlight=array();`

```
foreach($highlight as $k=>$v)
    {

        foreach($v as $n)
        {
         $string['word']= highlight_phrase($string['word'], $n, '<span style="color:#990000">', '</span>');

        }  
        }
$data[] ='<div class="Popup"><a href="#megssage"  onclick="show_pop(\''.str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $string['words']).'\')"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></a>
        <textarea name="txtwords[]" class="PopupText" id="txtwd" readonly="readonly" onDblClick="ToggleReadOnlyState('.$string['id'].')" >'.$string['word'].'</textarea></div>';
```

I have used the above `$string['word']` in text area but instead of highlighted text i am getting output as `<span style="color:#990000">Good</span> Articel` **Good** is the word to be highlighted exists in variable `$highlight=array();`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include [jQuery highlightTextarea](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) plugin.

And try like this:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5">Lorem ipsum hello  </textarea>

<script>
  $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate']
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer yes in jquery i have tried this, but pls provide  answer in php codeigniter.